# What is that Menu called? (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am making a plugin for intellij and i would like to put my plugin there. [image]

Comment: It is a toolbar and looks like a Navigation Bar. You can check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customize-actions-menus-and-toolbars.html for more information about menus and toolbars in intelliJ.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash those are Tool Windows.

Comment: Thanks, @KarthikeyanVaithilingam for the information.

Comment: Thanks for the answers it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [Tool Window Bars](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-windows.html#bars_and_buttons).

Check out the [plug-in development documentation](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/user_interface_components/tool_windows.html) if you want to add your own Tool Window.